# How to Scan QR code using webcam and php or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, qr-code

I am trying to implement QR code. i've successfully implement it using phpqrcode. However I don't know about how to decode the QR code using webcam and php or javascript. I've tried to search it on google, but can't find any solution for this. Anyone could help me? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this [jquery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) and then send the image to [php-zbarcode](https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode). It uses [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) which can read qrcodes. Note that the plugin requires flash.

There is also [jsqrcode](https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode) which you could use to scan and interpret the QR Code, however this requires HTML5 for displaying the webcam output, and flash for capturing.

[Here is a previous question pertaining to javascript-only solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733975/what-javascript-qr-code-reading-libraries-are-available)

Comment: Sir do you have a running code for this? reading qr code using pc camerea in php ? i cannot run it locally. pls healp