# How to create mobile, tablet, desktop viewable web template

Tags: html, css, mobile, tablet

I want to create same category two templates. First one for tablet, laptop and desktop viewable to any screen size and second one for mobile viewable to any screen size.

How can I create all device (mobile, tablet, laptop and desktop any screen size) viewable template?

I searched last two week in google to find out the above question answer but I unfortunately I don’t find any useful link. So please, anyone can help me giving above question answer (any useful link or details description). Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make QR codes in perl cgi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980976/how-to-make-qr-codes-in-perl-cgi) **or** [in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php) **or** [something else](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+generate+qr+code+%22INSERT+LANGUAGE+HERE%22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those kind of templates are really hard to find unless u pay fo them.
Just have a look on this :
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/