# How can I get a QR code without JavaScript tracking?

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am helping design a small web site for a local nonprofit group and wanted to include a QR code for easy access. I have generated a few such codes from "free" web-based services, and then examined the codes. All the generated codes do contain the web site, but I also noticed that all of the QR codes have JavaScript calls to PageTracker quietly appended to the end of the code block. In all the articles I have read about QR codes, nobody has discussed these largely invisible additions.

Given that I was not asked if I wanted these functions appended, I assume that the use of these QR codes is tracked by Google Analytics for the various sites that provide the QR code generation service (I have included an example of the JavaScript at the bottom of this question.)

I am not thrilled about my website user's (and their mobile phones) being tracked by a third party without either my or their permission. So given that, my question is two-fold: 1) Is there an easy way to get a QR code without the stealthy tracking (i.e. it just opens my web site)?  --and if not--  2) Is there any way that I can benefit from the Google Analytics data generated?

Thank you!

```
`<script type="text/javascript">`
`var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");`
`document.write(decodeURIComponent("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));`
`</script>`

`<script type="text/javascript">`
`var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-788492-5");`
`pageTracker._initData();`
`pageTracker._trackPageview();`
`</script>`
```

Comment: This might be of interest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542632/qr-code-generation-library-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the [ZXing QR code generator](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) does any funny business. It's [open source](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) so you can inspect the [generator source code](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fzxing.appspot.com%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fweb%2Fgenerator%2Fclient) to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Google Charts for this in a few projects and while I can't say what kind of logging they do on their side it certainly doesn't add anything on your side.

Just insert this as an image on your site: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20stackoverflow&choe=UTF-8

[image: Sample image with the url above]

You can find more info about it here: https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes