# Generating a barcode/qr code to contain a user ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question:  How would I go about implementing a type of barcode or qr code that would contain a users id that a phone like the IPhone could scan and retrieve the user account id?

My Thoughts:  I could just implement some sort of open source generator or create a type of generator that could be implemented on a web page and create a application that would just open the camera and scan the image.

I been checking out different types of generators like [here](http://www.barcodelink.net/) - which generates a link inside a qr code.  But one thing I don't see is how they generate that onto the screen.

Comment: You can find QR Code generators.  Just search php QR Code generator, or some other server side language.  I think the real problem is going to be accessing the camera.

Comment: Is there a way to tell a client side lang that an Android phone is active and to access a, lets say Java SDK applet or something of that sort to run an application for the camera is a button or something is clicked?  Not to worried about the IPhone right now and I know with IPhone I will have to create a separate application because Apple is anl.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that just through an applet.  I think the only way is through something like phonegap or Sencha.  Essentially, you are building an app with javascript, html, css, but their api's allow you to connect to hardware on the mobile devices.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the information.  I didn't know PHP would be used to generate the QR code!  http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @James, quick question so with when it comes to being able to scan it on the Android, I would need some API to access the camera to implement onto a website application?  Also do you know any sources to be able to than read it?

Comment: Well there are some new things that may allow you the ability to use things like camera and microphone without any native api's.  [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676036/can-you-launch-the-native-camera-app-from-an-html-5-web-app) With the QR Reader I'm not sure, probably just more research.

Comment: @James, `getUserMedia()`, while not supported well now, is not far off.  http://caniuse.com/stream  Looks like Blackberry is currently ahead of the curve.

Comment: Sweet I will check these out!  Phonegap looks like that will probably be my best solution as of now.

Answer (score 1):

See This :-
[QR code generation library in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542632/qr-code-generation-library-in-javascript)

The only QR code library i found useful is this:- http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/

LIVE demo :- http://debconf11.com/?f