# Create a QR code to a specific paypal checkout option

Tags: paypal, qr-code

I have a website that uses paypal to allow students to purchase a textbook. I am interested in making a QR code that when scanned brings students directly to the paypal app (or the web based address). Is there a tool that would allow me to do that fairly simply

I imagine since the paypal button takes me to a link, I can somehow generate a QR code that takes people to the same link? Or is that the wrong way to do it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the paypal link includes all of the necessary information, then you could take that link and use [this generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542632/qr-code-generation-library-in-javascript).

Comment: Is there a way to go to the paypal mobile site?

Comment: @user1357015 https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/  That might have what you're looking for. I've never included paypal in anything I've done, but it seems like you meed to use this, or if you could figure out what part of the link contains your merchant information then you could see if it would work with paypal's moble site (I don't know what it is, but presumably something like mobile.paypal.com/?yourmerchantinfo) and that might work.